# Sharing SQL Server Between Multiple System

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I have three computer in a office and I have installed my C#-2005 Project on all three

computers. But Problem is that Boss wants Sql-server-2000 on One PC out of three and other

would share the same.

I don’t know how to share Sql-server-2000 between three PC?. How to do?.

### Confusion:-

Thanks for your co-operation but here I have a confusion on majority people said to check

**TCP/IP** address and consider the Connection string as per main server from client PC.

Suppose I have financial project and there would be thousand of connection string in a

project. As per above I have to change thousand of connection string as per main pc.

Now think it is a one customer's  need If I have ten cutomer having same offer than think How much time I have to waste on it?. I have to modify thousand of connection string ten time more?.

If it is true than it will take lots of time on installation to each customer.

**I don’t know if it is only way?.**

The Connection string I have utilized on my each winform is as below:

```
string connstr = "server=.;initial catalog=maa;uid=mah;pwd=mah";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
conn.Open();
```

Here suggested about Config File and same I don't know if some body give me idea about how to consider it with my C#2005 project than it will save my lots time.

Comment: if the three machines are connected via LAN then just use the IP address of the machine where SQLserver is installed to connect to it from the other two.

Comment: You don't need to "share" SQL Server...you just need to have the client tools installed on the other two and the application can connect to the database on the third machine.

Comment: @StingyJack Sharing means Only one computer stored sql server and other shared it like read and write data.

Comment: @Mahesh, then thats the way SQL was designed to work. One instance, many callers.

Comment: @StingyJack, Interesting One Instance,many callers, how can you explain in details or suggest proper way?.

Comment: @Mahesh - The answers cover it pretty well. If you are unfamiliar with some of them, perhaps a bit more research on the subject will help.

Comment: "there would be thousand of connection string in a project." - there shouldn't be. The connection string should appear once, in a config file, and everything that wants a connection should then read it from config. Without knowing what data access tech you're using, I can't give a concrete example.

Comment: @mahesh, you dont have the connection string embedded IN the code do you?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I don't have idea about config file before that's why I have put connection string on each form as per requirement. For your consideration I can show you how I adjust it on each Form

Comment: @mahesh - if you have 1000 winforms that are directly accessing the db, perhaps you should read this... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns and a bit about MVC or MVP patterns. Writing software the way you are now is going to cause you many headaches in the future.

Comment: @StingyJack, Many thanks for guide me at proper direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you connect to the database in your code, you'll need a database connection string of some sort somewhere in there.   Figure out the connection string for the Database server and set your code to point to that database server's connection info; I bet you currently you have it pointed at *localhost*

If you're using SQL Server you may need to enable remote connections on the database server.

added:  you may need to modify firewall settings as well to allow SQL Server traffic (thanks Jared)

.

***Edit***: For putting the configuration string into a central location.

**Your posted code**

```
string connstr = "server=.;initial catalog=maa;uid=mah;pwd=mah";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
conn.Open();
```

**Change to**

Assuming your application has a App.Config file then you'd add an entry in there like

```
<add key="DBConnectionString" value="server=.;initial catalog=maa;uid=mah;pwd=mah"/>
```

And change your C# code to be like

```
string connstr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConnectionString"];
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
conn.Open();
```

Putting the ConfigManager call into a class might be a good idea if you have a lot of settings to retrieve and/or believe the configuration storage methodology might change down the road.  Going with the above example is WAY better than having the string literal scattered throughout your code.

Comment: As Damien said in his comment on your question, the connection string value should be stored once and once only, such as in a configuration file.  If you have the connection string text scattered throughout your code, then you're going to have the exact problem it sounds like you're having.  Changing your code to point to a centrally stored connection string value is going to be the way to go; this shouldn't be too difficult a change.

Comment: I have utilized using System.Configuration in application but There are ConfigurationManager class is not found in such assembly. what am I missing?.

Comment: it solve the problem that I have add System.configuration dll to assembly and it works but here still the problem is as it is. the above throw error like: "The ConnectionString Property has not been Initialize"

Answer (score 2):

Enable the`TCP/IP` connection in SQL Server. So that you can connect remotely from any pc within the network

check [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/57959f1a-7fb3-48e3-9e60-653f6dec9fd6/)

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that you embedded your connection string in the code, then you are going to have to do some refactoring. These would be the general steps, you will have to tailor them a bit to your situation.

1. Add your connection string to the app.config file.
2. Create a static/shared method that will read the connection string from the
   config file.
3. Do a find and replace in your solution to replace all
   of the hard coded connection strings in your code with the (class
   and) name of the method that gets the connection string.

This is probably going to be easier than rewriting all of your data calls to use something like enterprise library or EF.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do as the others suggested, such as changing the connection string and enabling TCP/IP within SQL Server, but you will also likely need to configure your firewall to allow requests to SQL Server (default port of 1433) through.