# How to choose GUID as the primary key in SQL compact?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, sql-server-ce-4

Hi I create C# windows form project and use "Microsoft® SQL Server® Compact 4.0 SP1" as database. I create my project with entity framework and code first approach. but I get some error. I want use GUID as type of primary key for tables and my code is:

```
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid id { get; set; }
```

but I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Server-generated keys are only supported
> for identity columns. The column 'id' has type
> 'SqlServerCe.uniqueidentifier', which is not a valid type for an
> identity column.

and when remove [DatabaseGenerated] and [key] I get duplicate error.
I searching and find SQL Compact in entity framework only knows int and big int as primary key and auto increment it, but I am not sure.
how can i fix this and use GUID and primary key? pleases help.

Comment: You can't. You need to either use a different database that supports auto-generated GUIDs or use a different data type. Microsoft stopped development of SQL Server CE in favour of recommending SQLite for file-based databases, so that would be the first place to look. I'm not sure whether it supports auto-generated GUIDs or not.

Comment: Please apply relevant tags and only relevant tags. Regardless of your application, this question has nothing to do with SQL or WinForms.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081096/entity-framework-6-guid-as-primary-key-cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column

Question is answered here.

The trick is to modify the OnCreate bit in the migration file.

Comment: Remove the Identity attribute and assign a unique guid in code

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you. I finally try and learn how to use SQLite. almost all my of problem solved.